# LightSwitch Application Localization Issue

Tags: lightswitch-2013

I'm using LightSwitch 2015, trying to localize application using this code:

```
Dim MyCulta = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo('ar')
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = MyCulta
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = MyCulta
```

But there is no any effect happens on screen. Do I need to refresh something after this code?

It's a desktop application & I have resource files for 'ar' language both Service & Client.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Do you already try it on InitializeDataWorkspace event? I use following code in my Screen.

```
Dispatchers.Main.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("id-ID");
});
```

Cheers